# Read all files containing specific word in R

Tags: r

I have 10 files in a folder named:

```
data_2008.txt

...

data_2017.txt
```

Instead of reading the data like this:

```
read.table(myfolder\data_2008.txt)

...

read.table(myfolder\data_2017.txt)
```

Is there a smart way where I can read all the files containing the name "data_" in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code

```
fileList <- list.files(path="myFolder", pattern="data_\\d{4}\\.txt")
tableList <- lapply(fileList, read.table)
```